# Oracle 12c IMPDP errors

Tags: oracle12c, impdp

The import command...

> impdp user/password DIRECTORY=desktop_import DUMPFILE=SENIORS4_Feb1.dmp TABLES=(DOCUMENT_PUBLISH, MEDIA_APPLICANT) REMAP_TABLESPACE=SENIORDB:import_user REMAP_SCHEMA=SENIORDB:import_user

...causes these errors:

> Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>
> ORA-39002: invalid operation
>
> ORA-39166: Object IMPORT_USER.MEDIA_APPLICANT was not found or could not be exported or imported.
>
> ORA-39166: Object IMPORT_USER.DOCUMENT_PUBLISH was not found or could not be exported or imported.

When I searched the web, most of these errors were associated with problems creating log files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to precede table names with their owner name, i.e.

```
TABLES=(SENIORDB.DOCUMENT_PUBLISH, SENIORDB.MEDIA_APPLICANT)
```

or even by enclosing both of them into double quotes, such as

```
TABLES=("SENIORDB"."DOCUMENT_PUBLISH", "SENIORDB"."MEDIA_APPLICANT")
```